# libgdx suddenly stopped being able to load images/textures?

Tags: java, libgdx

So I fired up IntelliJ and created a new libgdx project, imported it and everything and then I tried to run the DesktopLauncher to see if it would work and I got this error message:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load file: badlogic.jpg
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap.<init>(Pixmap.java:140)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.FileTextureData.prepare(FileTextureData.java:64)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.load(Texture.java:130)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:121)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:100)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:92)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:88)
    at com.blobb.game.PongGame.create(PongGame.java:16)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:136)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:114)
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: File not found: badlogic.jpg        (Internal)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.read(FileHandle.java:136)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.readBytes(FileHandle.java:220)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap.<init>(Pixmap.java:137)
... 9 more

Process finished with exit code 0
```

It was working fine before, plus I checked the assets folder in both "core" and "android" folders and they both had the badlogic.png file in them. What could be going on?

Comment: try opening the badlogic.jpg file to make sure its not corrupt

Comment: I tried running it in Eclipse and it worked fine. What could be wrong with IntelliJ?

Comment: i dont think projects and transferable from eclipse to intellij unless using gradle but even then I am not sure

Comment: can you open the linked assets folder from the desktop project?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you set everything up according to tutorials so I assume that everything was initially correct. Nevertheless some things like linked Assets folder is simply not imported.

You can try the method described [here](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/importing-eclipse-projects-into-intellij-idea.html). To be honest I didn't tried it myself but some people were successfully using it.

(See [here](http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php?topic=30803.0) for a discussion concerned with your problem in general)

Comment: Thanks for helping. I actually figured it out and got it working. Apparently I missed a step when setting up the run configurations. But now I have a new error :( When importing a new Gradle project it always gets stuck on "Gradle: Configure Projects"